# how to access android app database centerally

Tags: android, sqlite

In a normal android app ,we can code and create a sqlite database for an android app,But when we are putting this app on play store and multiple users are using that app, then how can we provide same kind of data to all users as database(sqlite) we made is only to that user in his phone.
I am new to android programming so not sure how to maintain a centralized database.

Comment: use content providers

Comment: k.how can we use content providers in maintainig the data same for all.can u please tell me in detail

Answer (score 0):

If you want centralized data for all users of your app, regardless of the device, then you'll need to use a cloud type API (e.g. web app backend accessed via REST API).  Anything you put in a SQLite database on the device will only be accessible by that app on that specific device and for that specific person.  On Android devices with multiple people, such as a tablet with multiple profiles, each person gets a separate instance of your app and data.

Comment: is the REST API the solution that every android app developer uses or they use something more generalized sir?

Comment: No, not at all.  It's the current trend when dealing with web-accessible backend servers.  You could do this via a SOAP style interface or other API.  The point is that for all devices to get the same data, you need to store it in a central location like a backend server.

Comment: which means everybody uses the same web service api for storing data at one server whether it can be a REST or SOAP styled store.correct @larry

Comment: Correct.  That is what you are trying to accomplish, right?

Comment: yes.right.I want to make an ecommerce app.so i think the approach which u have told,i should follow that for my required completion task